# How to get the remaining time from 24 hours in C#

Tags: c#

This is currentTime(EST) "2015-09-20 04:25:49.090". I need the below calculation.

1. Remaining time of "2015-09-20 04:25:49.090" this day (Ex : remaining time of this day is : 19 hours 35 minutes)
2. againg i have subtract from 24 hours - remainingTime (With minutes)

Could you please suggest me the solution for this?

Regards,
Arun

Comment: Note that if you're in Eastern Time, you're probably in EDT, not EST...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure - you do exactly as you've described, using `TimeSpan`. You can get the time of day from a `DateTime` using the [`TimeOfDay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday) property, and then just subtract that from 24 hours:

```
// You could use TimeSpan.FromDays(1) as well
var remaining = TimeSpan.FromHours(24) - dateTime.TimeOfDay;
```

Now, one thing to be wary of is that this doesn't necessarily give you the amount of time left in the day - because "local" days can be different lengths depending on time zone changes (e.g. for daylight saving time). If you need to take *that* into account (e.g. that on November 1st at 00:30 in New York, there's 24 1/2 hours left in the day...). That's a more complicated question - especially if you *also* need to take account of time zones where the day doesn't always start at 00:00.

As for the second part of getting "24 hours - remaining time" - that's just "the time of day", as you've got `24 hours - (24 hours - x)` which is just `x`.

Comment: var remaining = TimeSpan.FromHours(24) - dateTime.TimeOfDay; i need to get final value, which means again subtract with 24  - remaining

Comment: @Arunkumar: I don't know what you mean... Isn't that just TimeOfDay? It would help if you could be clearer in your question.

Comment: Result = 24 hours - ( 24 hours - 2015-09-20 04:25:49.090);

Comment: I need the above calculation only.

Comment: @Arunkumar: You do realize that y-(y-x) is just x, right? Why bother with the 24 hour part if you just need "the time of day as a timespan"?